# Can't load r package png

Tags: r

I get the following error as I try to install the package:

```
installing the source package ‘png’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/png_0.1-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 24880 bytes (24 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 24 KB

* installing *source* package ‘png’ ...
** package ‘png’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include   `libpng-config --cflags` -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c dummy.c -o dummy.o
/bin/sh: libpng-config: command not found
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include   `libpng-config --cflags` -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c read.c -o read.o
/bin/sh: libpng-config: command not found
read.c:3:10: fatal error: 'png.h' file not found
#include <png.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [read.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘png’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/png’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status
```

I was able to solve it by installing MacPorts pnglib, but I've encountered a new problem

```
installing the source package ‘jpeg’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/jpeg_0.1-10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 18667 bytes (18 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 18 KB

* installing *source* package ‘jpeg’ ...
** package ‘jpeg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c read.c -o read.o
In file included from read.c:1:
./rjcommon.h:11:10: fatal error: 'jpeglib.h' file not found
#include <jpeglib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [read.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘jpeg’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/jpeg’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jpeg’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/q4/3t808ybx4sj8m638h6gtd72h0000gn/T/RtmpfIaIYv/downloaded_packages’
```

I really don't understand this. Can you please help me once more?

Comment: start a fresh session of `RStudio` without any `packages` loaded and then try installing it again.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't install the libpng dependency. Since this is a system requirement, it needs to be done outside of R. You're on macOS, so you might want to use [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/libpng/) or [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libpng) for that.

Comment: I was able to solve it with installing MacPorts pnglib, but I've encountered a new problem with the jpeg package. I installed the jpeg in Macports but still have the error